# Bone Roll and transform lock, is there a trick to getting bones that face the right way for child's rotation?

Tags: bones, constraints, transform-orientation

I've tried every imaginable combination of Roll value and "Inherit Orientation" for both parent and child both Before and After creating the child.

When I create my child bone (a horizontal one) and try to Bone Constraint it with "Limit Rotation"

and all Axi limited with Z limited at -90°, +90° it just faces the other way.

How do I get the child to understand that 0 degrees for it is supposed to be "North" not "South"?

It just utterly refuses to face the way I choose.

No matter how many times I recreate it or it's parent. or start from scratch.

This is armature view, as you can see , the roll is set to 0 same for parent :
[image: tank side]

This is the pose mode view, simply adding the values to Transform lock rotated the bone backwards.
if I then test posing I can bear witness to it allowing rotation at the back face of the tank and preventing rotation at the front face. It is reverse to what I want and not even godly powers could make it otherwise as  far as I can tell :
[image: tank above]

I started from scratch again. still the same thing :
[image: in action]

Even if I rotate the entire set of bones 180° (with R) either in object or edit mode, and reposition them to the tank mesh in Armature it still flips the turret bone when I enable Z rotate limiter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107948/discussion-on-question-by-tatsu-bone-roll-and-transform-lock-is-there-a-trick-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you give the *Limit Rotation* constraint to your bone it rotates the bone to its 0/0/0 rotation position because by default the constraint is set to the *World* orientation. You need to switch the *Convert* setting to *Local Space*, or *Local Space With Parent*.

Comment: World Space is the wrong default for bones. Take note blender devs.